# Generators for the group of linear transformation preserving $x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2$?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, multilinear-algebra

When I have a quadratic form, such as $Q = x^2 + y^2 - 2z^2$, how do I find generators for the group that preserves this quadratic form?  That group would also be called $SO(Q)$ or $SO(3,Q)$.

---

If instead I put $Q_0 = x^2 + y^2 - z^2$, it says on Wikipedia [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triple):

- $\displaystyle A =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & -2 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -2 & 3 \end{array}\right] $
- $\displaystyle B =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & \;2 & \;2 \\ 2 & \;1 & \;2 \\ 2 & \;2 & \;3 \end{array}\right] $
- $\displaystyle C =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -1 & 2 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 3 \end{array}\right] $

So it was possible to find three matrices that generate $SO(3, Q_0)$.  Here it's a subset of $SO(2,1, \mathbb{R})$

[Here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/descentPythag.pdf) it's called "Pythagorean [descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_along_torsors)". Here "descent" could mean something very [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_(mathematics)).

---

Mathoverflow [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76352/orthogonal-group-of-quadratic-form?noredirect=1&lq=1)] says orthogonal groups of integral quadratic forms are "arithmetic lattices" and seems to reduce it to a computer problem.

Comment: You don't specify but it sounds like you want the group of matrices *over $\mathbb{Z}$* preserving the quadratic form? Over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ this is easy since you can scale. The use of "descent" here is meant to invoke Fermat's method of infinite descent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) and is unrelated to descent along torsors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that Wikipedia article talks about $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and then about $p = a^2 + b^2 = (a+bi)(a-bi)$ or the "splitting of primes" in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and then it talks about Galois Cohomology and Elliptic curves.  The writing drifts off to infinity...

Comment: Look, I'm not the one who used the word "descent" here, I'm just trying to explain what it means.

Comment: Great discovered by Green. I did not know this interesting and beautiful fact.

Answer (score 1):

as far as Bergren's tree of triples, with $x,y,z > 0,$ then $\gcd(x,y,z)=1,$ we can reduce $z$    as long as $x \neq y.$   Thus any triple descends to $(1,1,1).$

If $x > y$  and $x < \frac{4}{3} z$  let
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (-3x+4z, y, -2x + 3z ).  $$
Note that this uses $ 0 < z < x < z \sqrt 2 < \frac{3}{2} z$  and $0 < (3 - \sqrt 8)z < -2x + 3z < z.$

If $x > y$  and $x \geq  \frac{4}{3} z$  let
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (3x-4z, y, -2x + 3z ).  $$

If $x < y$  and $y < \frac{4}{3} z$  let
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (x, -3y + 4z, -2y + 3z ).  $$

If $x < y$  and $y \geq \frac{4}{3} z$  let
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (x, 3y - 4z, -2y + 3z ).  $$

Note that it is not possible to get $x$ or $y$   equal to zero when $z$ is nonzero.

These linear mappings are invertible over the integers  so everything ascends from $(1,1,1)$

As far as the entire group, it should not be difficult to show that an automorphism matrix can be reduced to the identity   with the linear mappings above, their inverses, and mappings corresponding to negating one of $x,y,z$  or corresponding to switching $x,y.$ Inequalities